Navigate to the next page, scrape data, and return to the first page
When scraping data from the first page, I navigate to the second page and click on the first link. After returning, the scraper navigates back to the first page instead of staying on the second page. Why is it not retaining the current page. How do we retain on the current page?
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from pymongo import MongoClient
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# MongoDB Connection
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['report_db']
collection = db['report']

# Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# Initialize the WebDriver using ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

# Open target website
driver.get('https://www.abogacia.es/servicios-abogacia/censo-de-letrados/')
print('Website opened')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Accept cookies if the button appears
try:
    cookies_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll")))
    cookies_button.click()
except Exception as e:
    print("Cookies button not found or already accepted.")

# Switch to iframe for interaction
iframe_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[contains(@src, "censo.abogacia.es")]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)

# Enter search query and submit
input_value = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="j_id23:j_id33"]')))
input_value.send_keys('a')

time.sleep(10)

# Handle ElementClickInterceptedException
submit_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "Buscar")]')))
try:
    submit_element.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Initial click failed: {e}")
    # Scroll into view and click using JavaScript as a workaround
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", submit_element)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit_element)

print('Website form submitted within iframe')


def get_existing_names():
    """Retrieve all first names from the database and store them in a set for fast lookup."""
    return {entry["first_name"] for entry in collection.find({}, {"first_name": 1, "_id": 0})}


existing_names = get_existing_names()

def insert_data_mongo(first_name,nombre, colegio, alta_colegiacion, n_colegiado, ejerciente, residente, direccion_profesional, telefono,fax):
    try:
        data = {
            "first_name":first_name,
            "Nombre": nombre,
            "Colegio": colegio,
            "Alta_Colegiacion": alta_colegiacion,
            "N_Colegiado": n_colegiado,
            "Ejerciente": ejerciente,
            "Residente": residente,
            "Direccion_Profesional": direccion_profesional,
            "Telefono": telefono,
            "Fax:":fax
        }
        # Insert the data into MongoDB
        collection.insert_one(data)
        print("Inserted data into MongoDB successfully")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error inserting data: {e}")


def extract_information(driver):
    """Extract information from the webpage based on given labels."""
    labels = {

        "first_name":"first_name",
        "Nombre:": "Nombre",
        "Colegio:": "Colegio",
        "Alta Colegiación:": "Alta Colegiación",
        "N. Colegiado:": "N. Colegiado",
        "Ejerciente": "Ejerciente",
        "Residente": "Residente",
        "Dirección Profesional:": "Dirección Profesional",
        "Teléfono:": "Teléfono",
        "Fax:": "Fax"
    }

    result = {}
    for label, key in labels.items():
        try:
            label_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//label[text()='{label}']")
            sibling_span = label_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "following-sibling::span")
            result[key] = sibling_span.text.strip()
        except Exception:
            pass  # Skip missing elements gracefully
    return result


# Main extraction loop with retry mechanism for handling stale element exceptions
i=0
while True:
    # Handling table details
    detail_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//table[@class='iceDatTbl tablaElementos']//tbody"))
    )

    rows = detail_element.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//td[contains(@style, 'width:140px')]")

    for page_number in range(len(rows)):
        time.sleep(5)
        
        try:
            detail_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//table[@class='iceDatTbl tablaElementos']//tbody"))
            )
            rows = detail_element.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//td[contains(@style, 'width:140px')]")
            
            if page_number < len(rows):
                current_row = rows[page_number]
                name_element = current_row.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span")
                name_text = name_element.text.strip()
                print(name_text)

                if name_text in existing_names:
                    print(f"{name_text} already exists in the database, skipping...")
                    continue

                            # Click the name link to go to the detail page
                name_element.click()
                time.sleep(5)

                # Extract information on the detail page
                info = extract_information(driver)
                first_name = name_text
                nombre = info.get("Nombre", "")
                colegio = info.get("Colegio", "")
                alta_colegiacion = info.get("Alta Colegiación", "")
                n_colegiado = info.get("N. Colegiado", "")
                ejerciente = info.get("Ejerciente", "")
                residente = info.get("Residente", "")
                direccion_profesional = info.get("Dirección Profesional", "")
                telefono = info.get("Teléfono", None)
                if telefono == "":
                    telefono = None
                fax = info.get("Fax", None)
                if fax == "":
                    fax = None

                # Insert the data into MongoDB
                insert_data_mongo(first_name, nombre, colegio, alta_colegiacion, n_colegiado, ejerciente, residente, direccion_profesional, telefono, fax)


                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='j_id23:j_id50']"))
                ).click()
               
                time.sleep(5)


                # Ensure you're still on the same page and handle the CAPTCHA

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing row {page_number}: {e}")
            continue

    # Pagination to the next page
    next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@id='j_id23:j_id79']")
    next_page.click()
    i += 1
    print(f"page_number-{i}")
    time.sleep(5)

